# Will users get Apple Push Notification Message after App Transfered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

We had implemented **APNS** in our app and it was working fine. But now we have **transferred this app** to client's account. And client has submitted new version of app to the app store using there account. So my questions are -

1. will old users with having older version of app and not updated new version of app yet (i.e which was submitted from our account and in which APNS  is configured with our account certificates and credentials) still get the push messages?
2. will new users with having newer updated version of app (i.e which is now submitted from client's account and in which APNS is configured with our account certificates and credentials) still get the push messages?
3. .pem file for APNS was generated from our account (before app transferred) and after app transferred also this .pem file is used. so do we need to create new .pem file for APNS using client's account ?

Please guide me on these issue.

Thank you

Comment: which .p12 and provisional profile used

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik .p12 and provisional profile for what ??

Comment: You need to create new .p2 and/or .pem file...

Answer (score 1):

Below are my suggestions..

1) YES, users with older versions will get push notifications.

2) NO, users will not get push notifications. As it is configured with your account.

3) YES, you need to create new .pem file with client account.

You need to see push notifications enabled or not at clients account and need to generate .p12 and .pem using clients account for making new users receive push notifications...

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 1):

in each app contains one private key, one public Key and one provisional profile . this is used for identify the each project. so in here you are used the old .pem and old .p12  and old .provisional profile

-- now you are using the New provisional profile and .p12, so you need to create the new .pem file for APNS , thats surely works and solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

1) yes, 2) yes, 3) no, you don't need to update the certificate.

Push notifications are routed based on an app's bundle identifier, so the Team ID does not enter into this at all. In other words, transferring the app doesn't affect push notifications provided that you keep the existing bundle identifier.

APNs TLS/SSL certificates are only for installing on your push server so it can connect to APNs. The APNs TLS/SSL certificate is completely separate from the provisioning profile and code signing certificate you use when building your app or submitting it to the App Store.

Thus, after transferring an application, the push certificate created in the old account is still able to send notifications to your app, even after publishing another update.

From a security standpoint, it would be best for the old account to revoke its push certificate and the new account to request a new push certificate and install that on the push server. But from a technical point of view it is not required to do this until the old certificate is about to expire.

I have verified this to be true after transferring applications. Last one was on january 2017.

Comment: one more question: Will old user with the new APNs certificate can still receive the push notification?

Comment: Yes because the new account is able to identify itself as owner of the bundle identifier of the app in the old user phone.